# Query with a meta value inside a given range

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

Quick question: I would like to retrieve some pages/posts with a meta value inside a range, eg) `$min<$meta_value<$max`

for ordinary $meta_value there was a way to get pages/posts like this:

```php
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => $key,
    'meta_value' => $meta_value, //$min<$meta_value<$max
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
...
);
$pages = get_pages( $args );
```

What is the best solution? should I first get them all and check them in an if condition or should I use `$wpdb->get_results($sql,OBJECT)` or is there a better way?

From SQL we have:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

Does the `WP_query` class have a method to use the `BETWEEN` keyword inside a query?

Comment: I fixed the code blocks, I would note that this kind of query will be expensive/slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation you will want to use the `meta_query` parameter, an example:

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query'  => array(
        array(
            'key'     => $key,
            'value'   => array($min, $max),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**The possible values for for the 'compare' key are:**

- "="
- "!="
- ">"
- ">="
- "<"
- "<="
- "LIKE"
- "NOT LIKE"
- "IN"
- "NOT IN"
- "BETWEEN"
- "NOT BETWEEN"
- "EXISTS" (only in WP >= 3.5)
- "NOT EXISTS" (only in WP >= 3.5)
- "REGEXP" (only in WP >= 3.7)
- "NOT REGEXP" (only in WP >= 3.7)
- "RLIKE" (only in WP >= 3.7)

Default value is "=".

**Useful reading:**

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/

Comment: Oh, thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @MartinSpinoza if this is the answer to your question can you mark it as the accepted answer so that Adam gets their reputation points? Otherwise the site will keep suggesting this question as needing an answer. It's the big check mark under the voting controls

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks. I did. Great community, I didn't expect to find my answer this soon. I wish I had more reputation to upvote this answer.